# To find the path of main project set in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7

I tried to get the path of main project set in Netbeans.

```
import org.netbeans.api.project.ui.OpenProjects;
import org.netbeans.api.project.Project;
import javax.tools.FileObject;

 Project proj = OpenProjects.getDefault().getMainProject(); 
FileObject root = proj.getProjectDirectory(); 
String path = root.getPath();
```

When executing the following error is generated. i found than fileUtil is to be used instead of the above root.getpath().

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/netbeans/modules/project/uiapi/Utilities
    at org.netbeans.api.project.ui.OpenProjects.<init>(OpenProjects.java:88)
    at org.netbeans.api.project.ui.OpenProjects.<clinit>(OpenProjects.java:83)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to search for the package in the module properties > Libraries > Add Dependency:

[image: netbeans module properties]

This however requires that in the Nebeans Platform project you've added dependency on that Platform Module (probably in ide > Project API)